# How do you recursively decrypt files of a certain file type via OpenSSL?

Tags: shell, encryption, openssl, samsung-smart-tv

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -K B1D5F122E75D757C79F48886D42F8E1A -in index.html.cmk  -nosalt -iv BFE932F9273DC2A0DFC93F0B8E7AC7C2 -out index.html
```

I am using this script to reverse engineer the firmware of a certain old Samsung Smart TV (ES8000 exactly). However, I want to decrypt all .cmk files in the current directory and make a decrypted version while keeping the encrypted files (or “/root/ /home/“) to decrypt all cmk files. Similarly I would also like to do the same with smk files as well.

```
  openssl aes-128-cbc -d -K 84AA59959849F6DDD4823B90F7913902 -in config.xml.smk -nosalt -iv 1DA76DE2A0EE55C0DBCCEDA772E3684D -out config.xml
```

I would like it as a single line shell script.

I don’t want to do it manually, I am quite new to programming and use of the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL can decrypt files recursively with the -r option.

Comment: How do you decrypt a specific file type and remove the extension of the decrypted, but keep the original file that is encrypted?